# convert asc to java

Tags: java, actionscript, red5

how can i convert my main.asc's code( server side of video conference with flash media server) to application.java (server side of video conference with Red5) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [j2as3 project](http://code.google.com/p/j2as3/). Does it suits your requirements?

Comment: Hi 
no, I wanna convert action script to java, but that link was for convert java to action script

Comment: Oh, my fault. j2as is much more common task - perhaps because no one knows ActionScript.:^)